# Constructing inputs with a given runtime for Insertion Sort

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, insertion-sort

Does anyone know of any good ways to go about doing this? It's easy to find families of inputs {I_i} where InsertionSort(I_i) \in \Theta(n) or \Theta(n^{2}

What about for values of k where 1 < k < 2?

Is it possible to find an input I so that InsertionSort(I) \in \Theta(n^{k})?

Comment: Think you meant 1 < k < 2, since it's never sublinear

Comment: That's correct , edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an n element list where the first n^(k/2) elements are decreasing [n^(k/2), n^(k/2)-1,...,1], and the remaining n-n^(k/2) elements are increasing [n^(k/2)+1, n^(k/2)+2,...,n]. Insertion sort is quadratic on the first part and linear on the second part. This is runtime Theta(n^k + n - n^(k/2)), which is Theta(n^k) as long as 1 < k < 2.